# Putting space in app name (CFBundleDisplayName)

Tags: ios

I am trying to put space in my app name, which is around 24 characters long. I am running the app on iOS 10+.

I have tried the following things/suggestions that I found on forums:

1) Simply putting space in `CFBundleDisplayName` in `plist` - XXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX - does not work, the space is automatically omitted

2) Using Unicode character `&#x2007;` -- Double space is seen in the app name when I see app name in app settings

3) `\U00A0app` --- Does not work

Tried couple of other Unicode characters instead of space, but nothing works.

Comment: Depending on the characters in app name and device, generally anything more than 16 characters will be truncated on any device. 24 seems too much for the app name.

Comment: Yes, but the requirement os the user is as such.. the full name with space should atleast be visible on settings page

Comment: &#x2007, works only when u typed in *.plist ,Can't be inserted in Display name in Xcode project settings.

Comment: @Mukesh yes i know that.. i have typed it in plist only (opened it as source code). But is is resulting in double space.